# jQuery .draggable without clicking

Tags: jquery, draggable, mousemove

I'm doing draggable div. I'm using jquery UI .draggable function fot that, but this is not exactly that what I need.

```
$('.magic_background').draggable({
            cursor: 'move', 
            containment: '.magic_movable'
        });
```

I need that the DIV would be draggable without clicking on it (function working with mousemove) . Also I need to remove drag cursor, what is the function for that what I want?

Comment: What is the UI experience going to be like if you don't click on something to begin dragging it?

Comment: I can't explain, but I need that the elements inside parent div would move on mousemove.

Comment: @StevenV actually I think he does not want exactly `draggable` but some sort of `mousemove` interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

Looks better **without jQuery UI** at least **works in Chrome.**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ozisax/10/edit)**

```
$(function(){

  var $par = $('.magic_movable'),
      $bg = $('.magic_background'),
      parW = $par.outerWidth(),
      parH = $par.outerHeight(),
      bgW = $bg.width()/2,
      bgH = $bg.height()/2,
      X, Y, posX, posY;

  var drag = 0; // flag


  $par.on('mousemove', function( e ){
    X = e.clientX - $(this).offset().left; // get mouse X position inside parent
    Y = e.clientY - $(this).offset().top;  // get mouse Y position inside parent
    posX = Math.min( Math.max(0, X-bgW), parW-(bgW*2) ); // containment X
    posY = Math.min( Math.max(0, Y-bgH), parH-(bgH*2) ); // containment Y
    if(drag){
       $bg.css({left:posX, top:posY}); // move element only if flag is true (1)
    }
  }).on('mouseleave', function(){
    drag = 0;                  // stop draggable on parent mouseleave
  });

  $bg.on('mouseenter', function( e ){
     drag = 1;                 // make draggable on mouseenter
  });

});
```

Comment: becouse this is not the same thing as I wanted. I need the same effect as dreggable but I dont need to click and keep clicked on div. It should be work with mousemove

Comment: thanks, it looks great but it haves 2 problems: it's not working with chrome and mousemove effect is not kind of that what i need. it moves, but when you pull up your mouse to up, than only mouse cursor moves up, the div stays..

Comment: @baitas212123 if you don't explain a bit more what you exactly want to do with this one and how to stop that event, I refuse to loose more time on that Q :\

Comment: thanks, this edit is good for me (with `mousemove`), but why is it not working with chrome?

Comment: @baitas212123 let me take a look

Comment: I want, but I can't do it :/ look, at your demo is not working with chrome, only with mozilla is working mousemove event

Comment: no, I mean give me the time to figure out a solution for you. lol